# How to add Reference?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly

I want to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference for my Windows Form Application. I am using Windows 8. I don't have this reference in neither my system nor my project.

Can anybody help from where can I get  it and add to my project??

Comment: have you Microsoft office installed in your OS ?

Comment: you checked the answer of Darren Davies and you don't find the dlls ?

Comment: ya its not on my disk and I couldn't find it for 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

You will need Microsoft Office installed on your machine.  Once you do, right click `References` in the Solution Explorer, then click `Add Reference`.

[image]

If you can't get Office and need to connect to Excel, take a look at this custom solution:

https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: @Darren..I tried this but this reference is not being listed

Comment: Click Browse and select the assembly on disk.

Comment: @Lasse..I don't have it on my disk